# How to 'Stick" OS X system Prefs for Language & Text

Tags: mac-osx-server

Master Client has UK English, UK Date Format and UK currency specified, yet on client's first login at any workstation, they note that Language & Text has defaulted to US rather than English United Kingdom ...

Where do I make this pref 'stick', please? on the Master Client prior to image creation? is there a particular preference I need to get synchronised at login/logout to retain this?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're using some sort of cloning system to image the client computers?  If so, the problem is likely that the the relevant preferences are stored in ByHost preference files, meaning that they only apply on one particular computer.  The reason for ByHost prefs is so that if you're using a network account and logging into multiple client computers, you can have separate settings for each one.  Unfortunately, this also means that when you clone one computer from another, the preferences stored in this format don't stick.

Most Mac imaging systems have an option to rename the ByHost preference files so they do apply to the newly imaged computer.  If you're doing the imaging manually, or using a system that doesn't have this option, you'll need to find a script that handles the renaming.  Unfortunately, after a little googling I can't seem to find a script to handle this, though I know they exist...

Comment: Setting up Master Client then applying SIU before NetRestoring the workstations. If Server and Master Client are both set up as UK English Date/Currency, why should initial logon introduce US Date Currency? am I missing something obvious, or is there a setting in SIU to retain these preferences?

Comment: @DaiVernon I haven't tested whether a basic-style NetRestore handles this, but if you use SIU in advanced mode (click the Customize button at the bottom of its window), you can add the "Apply System Configuration Settings" action to the image build process, and check its "Change ByHost preferences to match client after install" option.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work for me...